# Wpf Binding Confusion

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to learn on MVVM. I've understand the concept, however, i'm confused about the binding. I'm not sure where to bind my Fill property. Please help. Tqvm in advanced.

View - name: MainScreen.xaml

```
<Path Fill="{Binding mainScreenClass, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"/>
```

inCodeBehind

```
DataContext = new vmMainScreen();
```

ViewModel - name:vmMainScreen

```
public ICommand cmdMouseEnterNav { get; private set; }
public mMainScreen mainScreenClass { get; set; }
public vmMainScreen()
{
    mainScreenClass = new mMainScreen();
    mainScreenClass.propNaviconFill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    naviconMouseEventChecker();
}

private void naviconMouseEventChecker()
{
    cmdMouseEnterNav = new SimpleCommand
    {
        ExecuteDelegate = x => mainScreenClass.propNaviconFill = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#c5a02b"))
    };
}
```

Model - name:mMainScreen

```
public class mMainScreen : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Brush _NaviconFill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    public Brush propNaviconFill
    {
        get
        {
            return this._NaviconFill;
        }
        set
        {
            this._NaviconFill = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("propNaviconFill");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that when i breakpoint on my colorConverter, I'm getting the class. Not the property of propNaviconFill. If i create another property with the Brush class on my ViewModel and bind it to Fill, there is no problem. But that means I'm not following the correct structure of MVVM. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind to the property of your view model.

```
<Path Fill="{Binding propNaviconFill, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"/>
```

Use the view model implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` as the data context of your view.

```
DataContext = new mMainScreen();
```

If you really want to use `vmMainScreen` as your data context, then `vmMainScreen` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` there and you should study how `NotifyPropertyChanged` was used to notify the view that the view model property has changed.

Comment: oo so the datacontext of view should be going to the Model? Thats the correct structure for MVVM is it? View->Model->ViewModel? For the INotifyPropertyChanged, I think I`ve already managed to notify the View of changes in the property existing in the ViewModel. I created a property with the class of Brush and my View is binded to the property and it already works.

Comment: @ArifSam MVVM (Model View View Model) is a pattern where the View Model is the glue code between the View and Model so that View doesn't have to directly interact with the Model and vice versa. Only the view model should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Models should just be  POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) classes with minimal to no operations. Let your view model do the operations for your models.

Comment: I`m actually getting a bit too confused. haha. Sorry if i keep on asking the same question. Based on your answer, i need to attach the dataContext to the Model right? Based on this, any changes on the Model property should notifies the View. However, the main operation, that means my Command is in ViewModel and my ViewModel constructor is not called, because we have changed the dataContext = new Model();. Where do we instantiate my ViewModel? Thank you so much again.

Comment: Or am I implementing the MVVM all wrong based on my code?

Comment: @ArifSam `mMainScreen` is also functioning as a view model since it implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: Yup, you are mistaking a view model as your model. A simple example would be if I have a registration view then I should have a registration view  model. Inside my registration view model I would be using a class called User which is functioning as my model. my view model will now be in charge of creating my User object based on the user inputs from my view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147219/discussion-between-arif-sam-and-ephraim).

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind there are two basic types of MVVM:
1. View First
2. View Model First

Based on your example you are trying to do View First. This is easier to implement but comes with drawbacks on larger projects since the view controls the creation of the ViewModel it's harder to inject data or state into the ViewModel.

For all MVVM patterns you have the three parts:

**Model** - Basically a state bag. This thing is just like a customer class which most of the time implements INotifyProperty changed.

**ViewModel** - This is like the controller class in MVC. It has all the real logic and does the work.

**View** - This is your XAML and it only holds presentation logic. The code-behind class ie: MyWindow.xaml.cs should not be used except to setup the ViewModel if your going View First. (there are exceptions of course but generally it should basically be empty)

**For View First**
Your Window (or control) should create the ViewModel in the constructor and assign it to the DataContext.

Your ViewModel will have ICommand's, ObservableCollections and such that can be bound to controls in the View. So when your constructor fires you fill up your data and put it into the necessary structures; because of databinding this gets related to the View and shown.

Your Model (you usually have more than one, can have Customer, Order, StockTicker or whatever.) These are created by the ViewModel and put into things such as ObservableCollections for the View to databind to.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. I was confused on whether ViewModel allows the creation of property such as "public string name {get;set;}" in MVVM concept. Because this kind of property usually resides in Model. Then, i didnt know where to bind because my property all exists in Model and my View DataContext is on the ViewModel. Haha. Anyway, thanks for your help.